# Connect to a third party socket.io server

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm creating a socket.io server like so:

```
var http = require('http');
var io = require('socket.io');
var port = 8080;

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){ 
    res.writeHead(200,{ 'Content-Type': 'text/html' }); 
    res.end('<h1>Hello Socket Lover!</h1>');
});

server.listen(port);

// Create a Socket.IO instance, passing it our server
var socket = io.listen(server);
// Add a connect listener
socket.on('connection', function(client){ 
    console.log('Connection to client established');

    // Success!  Now listen to messages to be received
    client.on('message',function(event){ 
        console.log('Received message from client!',event);
    });

    client.on('disconnect',function(){
        clearInterval(interval);
        console.log('Server has disconnected');
    });
});

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:' + port + '/');
```

The server works fine and starts, however when I'm connecting through js like this:

```
$(function(){

var socket = io();
socket.connect('http://localhost:8080');

});
```

It's not connecting and I'm getting this in dev tools console.

```
polling-xhr.js:264 GET http://file/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lz53lhL net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

I'm loading socket.io.js like this:

```
<script src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$(function(){

var socket = io();
socket.connect('http://localhost:8080');

});
```

to

```
$(function(){

var socket = io('http://localhost:8080');

});
```

You need to pass the url of your socket server to the `io` function